# How to get the Profile name form the userinfo

Tags: apex, soql, integration, c#

> 1. I have integrated with the .net and I want the profile name from the login result. Is there any possible?

**Question 2:**

> 2. When we query the opportunity record in c#, i want the modified user name. so how to get the modified user name.

***Note: I got the modified-user id only. so how to get the username without query the user object.***

Answer (score 2):

Once you have a session you can call [`getUserInfo()`](http://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_getuserinfo.htm). In the [getUserInfoResult](http://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_getuserinfo_getuserinforesult.htm#topic-title) there is the `profileID` in the response.

Now that you have the profileId you can send a SOQL query off to [Profile](http://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_profile.htm) to get the Name field.

```
select id, name from profile where Id = '00e30000000hDW1AAM'
```

When performing a SOQL query against Opportunity you can get the last modified user name with `LastModifiedBy.Name`. E.g.

```
Select Id, Name, LastModifiedBy.Id, LastModifiedById, LastModifiedBy.Name From Opportunity
```

Comment: Great. Cant we get the profile name without querying the profile object?

Comment: I would like to avoid the query execution so can you let me know, any possible to get the profile name without querying the profile?

Comment: @Lemon Unless you are already sending a query to something like the User object you won't be able to get the Profile name without an additional query. You can use the userInfo from the LoginResult to save one API query. However, at some point you are going to need a query to go from the ProfileId to the Profile.Name.

Comment: can you provide the code snippet. i have used this line and what to do next. please am beginner so please let me know.     SFDCServices.Url = SFDCloginResult.serverUrl;

Comment: By the looks of it you can get the logged in users Profile Id with `SFDCloginResult.userInfo.profileId`. Then use your `SFDCServices` to call query against the Profile as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: yes SFDCloginResult.userInfo.profileId will contain the profile id, after that what should i do? cant get that point please clear me.

Comment: @Lemon Err, that depends on how you setup the web service. It may be something like: `QueryResult profileResult = SFDCServices.query("Select Id, Name from Profile where Id = '"+SFDCloginResult.userInfo.profileId+"'");`. You will then need to read the Name from the QueryResult.records.

Comment: this what I asked earlier. i dont want to query the profile object. so is there any way to get the profile name from the login result or some other way. i would like to avoid the more than query execution since the .net takes too much of time.

Comment: @Lemon No, there is no other way to get the Profile name from the LoginResult. The data simply isn't present in the LoginResult beyond the ProfileId.